# Difference between arrow function and variable = function(){}

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I am beginner in JavaScript and I have a question. What is the difference between these two functions.

```js
const one = function(n){
    console.log(n)
```

and this arrow function.

```js
const one = (n) => {
    console.log(n)
```

I know I am storing the value in `one` variable. But even then I can't find the difference between these

Comment: @Justinas — That's **a** difference. There are plenty of others. The duplicate question has answers which go into a decent amount of depth.